# Spectrum of Truth

Tags: logic, soft-question

I recently read about Godel's incompleteness theorem. In it the author said the completely innocuous statement that every statement is either true or false. My question is, is there any way of assigning a so called "truth weight" to a statement (i.e. saying "this statement is half true") is a logical way.

The best example I could think of of something that would fall somewhere between true and false is the statement
$$1+2+3+4+\dots = -1/12.$$
Clearly this statement is not true. However, if we let $\zeta(s)$ be the analytic continuation of the function
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}$$
then $\zeta(-1)=-1/12$. So there is some way of seeing this statement as somewhat true.

Comment: L.E.J. Brouwer wouldn't have considered it a "completely innocuous statement".

Comment: You can always change the context entirely to make almost any statement true. Even $0=1$ is true in some contexts.

Comment: Check out fuzzy logic

Comment: These aren't good examples - you're just providing two completely different formal statements, which could potentially be considered formalizations of $1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + \cdots = -1/12$, out of which the first is provably false and the second is provably true.  (e.g. the first formalization could be $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N > 0, \forall n \ge N, | (1 + 2 + \cdots + n) - (-1/12) | < \epsilon$, and the second would be a formalization of "there exists an analytic function on an open connected subset $U$ of $\mathbb{C}$ containing $\{ s : \mathrm{Re}(s) > 1 \}$ which agrees with...

Comment: See also http://karagila.org/2016/syntactic-t-rex-irregularized/

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$ for $\mathrm{Re}(s) > 1$ and has value $-1/12$ at -1.

Comment: A more interesting example would be the continuum hypothesis, for which it is proven both that $ZFC \not\vdash CH$ and $ZFC \not\vdash \lnot CH$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler The continuum hypothesis is not a good example for what I am asking as it is known to be undecidable, so we can't assign any value of truth to it. The example I gave can, arguably, be assigned some value of truth.

Comment: @Mastrel I think the point I was trying to make is: presumably, any "assignment of truth value" operation would have to operate on a formal statement with a clearly defined meaning, not on ambiguous natural-language statements.

Comment: @DanielSchepler This is precisely my question. Are there formal statements for these ambiguous natural language statements?

Comment: Masterl, would you say that $2+2=4$ is an indisputably true statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very good article by *Lambek* and *Scott* that seems related to your (and Pilate's) question "What is truth?":

> **What is truth?**
>
> What is truth? This question, once raised by *Pilate*, received different answers from different mathematicians.
>
> *Hilbert* famously proposed the problem of showing that mathematical
>   statements are true if and only if they can be proved. Like all of us, he assumed the set of proofs to be recursive.
>
> *Brouwer* once asserted that mathematical statements are true if and only
>   if they are known. In retrospect, he should have said “can be known”, if truth
>   is to be independent of time.
>
> *Gödel* believed that a (classical) mathematical statement is true if and only if it holds in some kind of Platonic universe, which we take to be a Boolean local topos in which numerals are standard.
>   It follows from Gödel’s incompleteness theorem that Hilbert’s position
>   is incompatible with the assumption that the Platonic universe is classical.
>   However, if we assume that this universe is intuitionistic (the free topos), there is no contradiction. Moreover, Brouwer’s modified position is vindicated if we interpret “knowable” as “provable”.
>
> *Tarski* defines truth differently. He said “p is true” instead of asserting p. ...

See [*J. Lambek, P. J. Scott, Reflections on a categorical foundations of mathematics, ch. 2.8*](http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~phil/papers/LS11.final.pdf)

*Lambek* and Scott reflect on possibilities to view Gödel's incompleteness theorems from another, topos theoretical perspective by replacing Gödel's **Platonic universe** (of classical models) by an **intuitionistic universe** (represented by the *free topos*).

### Topos theory

This is going to introduce you to **topos theory**: a **topos** contains a so called **suboject classifier** $\Omega$ that generally provides more truth values than just true and false. You might indeed see $\Omega$ as a *spectrum of truth*.

Non-classical truth spectra come up naturally e.g. with **variability** in the sense that something is always true, or never true, or is not currently true but will eventually be true.

### References

For an introduction see e.g.

(1) *Lawvrere, Sets for mathematics*

(2) *Lawvere, Conceptional mathematics*

(3) *Goldblatt, Topoi: the categorical analysis of logic*

You can find (1) and (2) via google. (3) is published at dover.

Some related introductory articles:

(4) [*John L. Bell, Abstract and Variable Sets in Category Theory*](http://publish.uwo.ca/~jbell/Bell2.pdf)

(5) [*Z. L. Low, What is ..a topos?*](http://zll22.user.srcf.net/talks/2013-01-17-WhatIsATopos.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a notion of *many-valued logic* - see https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-manyvalued/ for much more about this interesting topic in non-classical logic.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your specific example, but yes, it does make intuitive sense to say that certain statements are 'somewhat true' or 'largely true' or 'barely true' or ... and that is because many concepts we have are 'fuzzy', meaning that there are often grey areas where things are neither clearly false nor clearly true, and various non-classical logics try to deal with this.

For example, check out 'fuzzy logic': https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic